# Can malware spread from Tails to a computer's hdd?

Tags: tails, malware

This is more out of curiosity for me than anything.  I understand that Tails is a LiveUSB distro focused on Tor, etc.  My question is pretty simple: Is it possible for malware downloaded while in Tails to spread to the hdd?

This is assuming that the user did *not* intend to save files of any kind to the drive and did not intentionally mount the drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TAILS - LIVECD & RATs](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/tails-livecd-rats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, not just onto HDD, but even into BIOS and firmware - like [Rackshasta](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjV-eu__MLRAhVhQpoKHUB6BqkQtwIIGjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPE97Ajaaur8&usg=AFQjCNHc33PkQfmap20U8t8ncBe6bZAoaQ&sig2=a94y6wOsfPSChzu_xLlviw&bvm=bv.144224172,d.bGs). All software can have a zero-day exploits/vulnerabilities, including Tails. And it's OK - programs are written by people, people make mistakes, other people are finding these mistakes. *Any* OS and/or program can have this kind of risks, so don't blame Tails.

Comment: Why would Tails and any other linux system allow these malwares to self-execute themselves? Attacker has to find loopholes in tor browser to inject its malware into the host. Linux OS atleast has to approve the malware to access ROM and hard disk unless attacker finds a loophole to bypass them.

Comment: @AlanWatch using bugs [like this](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/10/most-serious-linux-privilege-escalation-bug-ever-is-under-active-exploit/) and tricking user into opening malware content. I don't say that it's a hell-easy task, it's definitely not, but it's possible